# how to embed node add form in a block?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

How to embed node add form in a block?

I have tried the following but it does not work. "free_listing2_node_form" is the form_id of the node add form I want to embed in this block.

If the approach below is right, I suspect problem in this statement

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('free_listing2_node_form');
```

Any help / direction is much appreciated!

```
<?php


function freelisting2_block_info() {
  $blocks['neil_recent'] = array(
    'info' => t('neil_Recent content'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function freelisting2_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'neil_recent':
      if (user_access('access content')) {
        $block['subject'] = t('Recent content');
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('free_listing2_node_form');
      }
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}


?>
```

(I am using Drupal 7)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$block['content'] = render(drupal_get_form('free_listing2_node_form'));
```

I didn't test it.

Comment: The code above seemed to behave weirdly and not the entire form was being visible...so i went with the option of using  The formblock module: http://drupal.org/project/formblock.... D7 release is still not in the green but got some feedback from a couple of folks in the irc chat rooms that it works OK...so will go with this for now. Thanks for the help/direction...

Comment: np, if that module help you use that, maybe you can add this code: render(drupal_get_form('free_listing2_node_form')); in block--myblock.tpl.php file. Try every solution you can find and let us know ;)